# In Android, how do I share (intent) using the Facebook application rather than via web?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

So far in Android I know how to wall post to the user's wall via the web but I'd like, the app to detect whether the user has the facebook application installed and if so post via that. Does anyone know how to do this?

My code so far is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static String FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "276023232498070";
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = 
            new String[] { "publish_stream","email","user_birthday","user_location" };

    private Facebook facebook;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        facebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("app_id", "276023232498070");
        parameters.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=myappistasty");
        parameters.putString("name", "This is the name of the link set in app.");
        parameters.putString("caption", "This is Text that is specified in bt the aoo");
        parameters.putString("picture", 
                "http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2012/11/15/article-0-1609D0FF000005DC-373_964x641.jpg");

        // Posting my message, maybe here i could add paramterers like icon and a link etc..?
        facebook.dialog(MainActivity.this, "feed", parameters,new PostDialogListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public abstract class BaseDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

    }

    public class PostDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
            if (postId != null) {
                Log.e("","Message posted on the wall.");
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            } else {
                Log.e("","No message posted on the wall.");
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get list of activities that can handle `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and find the facebook app.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "In Android, how do I share (intent) using the Facebook application rather than via web?");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495438");

PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List activityList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
    if ((app.activityInfo.name).contain("facebook")) {
        final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
        final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
        shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        shareIntent.setComponent(name);
        startActivity(shareIntent);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way of doing this is via the Share Dialog for Android:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/#linkshare